# How to configure JwtBearerOptions to include policy name in well-known openid-configuration URL?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to add some bearer token verification to my ASP.NET web application. I'm using the built-in JWT authentication code, configured to use the following code ...

```
services.AddAuthentication(ConfigureAuthentication).AddJwtBearer(ConfigureJwt);
```

Which runs the following functions ...

```
private void ConfigureAuthentication(AuthenticationOptions options)
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}

private void ConfigureJwt(JwtBearerOptions options)
{
    var directoryId = Configuration["AzureAd:DirectoryId"];
    var directoryName = Configuration["AzureAd:DirectoryName"];
    var policy = Configuration["AzureAd:SigninPolicyName"];

    options.Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:ApplicationId"];
    options.Authority = $"https://{directoryName}.b2clogin.com/{directoryName}.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0";
}
```

The `ConfigureJwt` method is the one I'm dealing with. I can't seem to get the underlying JWT code to fetch the `openid-configuration` from the appropriate URL. It's very close, but it's lacking the policy from the URL. Here is what my above code generates and tries to fetch the `openid-configuration` from ...

```
https://example-directory.b2clogin.com/example-directory.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

And here is what it is supposed to fetch the configuration from, as specified from the Azure portal ...

```
https://example-directory.b2clogin.com/example-directory.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_SignInPolicy
```

As you can see, my code above is lacking the policy name.

I can't seem to figure out how to specify this anywhere. Does anybody know how to configure `JwtBearerOptions` so that it includes this policy name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Authority needs to be:

```
https://{directoryName}.b2clogin.com/{directoryName}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin/v2.0
```

Replace *B2C_1A_signup_signin* with your policy id.

That contains the policy id and it'll download the metadata from the correct place.

Comment: Oh thanks. I hadn't seen that URL format mentioned anywhere else! It seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from a MS employee about how to appropriately do this. You can set the meta address, which is the address from which the configuration is fetched. This way you can keep the authority set to what Azure says it should be, meanwhile have a dynamic meta address. Below is how MS suggests solving this ...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<AuthenticationOptions>(configuration.GetSection("Authentication:AzureAd"));

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var authOptions = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<AuthenticationOptions>>();

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) // sets both authenticate and challenge default schemes
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.MetadataAddress = $"{authOptions.Value.Authority}/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={authOptions.Value.SignInOrSignUpPolicy}";
            options.Audience = authOptions.Value.Audience;
        });
}
```